# Ember.js how to get and pass data to re-useable views?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dry

I begin to learn Ember.js,but there is a problem:

I have a controller which name is dashboard,and it has view and template,but i insert views into dashboard such as statics view,profile view,they all have their own view and template,but i want to know how does this view get their data since they have no controller?should i pass them from dashboard controller or in my statics view get the data from server directly?

If i need to pass the data from the dashboard controller ,what's the best practice?

p.s. I want to reuse this views such as profile in other views

Comment: For these nested views do you need to fetch data from a server or does the dashboard already hold it?

Comment: @Nath dashboard doesn't fetch the data of the nested view,thus it's data model because complex,i looked at the discourse's source code ,and find that they use {{render}} and {{view App.UserView}} ,but still confused . I found that the Ember.js is a little like C# MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `render` helper. For example:

```
//in dashboard.hbs
{{render 'statics'}}
{{render 'profile'}}
```

With this approach Ember will automagically render your view/template in the context of  `App.StaticsController` and `App.ProfileController`. Of course you still need to provide data to these controllers - the ideal place to do that is from the route, something like

```
//in App.DashboardRoute.js
setupController: function() {
  this.controllerFor('statics').set('content', someData);
  this.controllerFor('profile').set('content', myProfile);
}
```